# How to make a link list in python by defining my own class?

Tags: python, class, linked-list

I tried making the link list as follows-

```
class node:
   def __init__(self,data=None,link=None):
        node.data = data
        node.link = link
class linkl:
    def __init__(self):
        linkl.start = None
    def add_at_begin(self,data):
        newnode = node(data,linkl.start)
        linkl.start = newnode
    def printlist(self):
        curr = linkl.start
        print(curr)
        while True:
            print(curr.data)
            curr=curr.link
            if curr.link == None:
               break
```

I tried using the list with the following-

```
linklist = linkl()
for x in range(3):
    linklist.add_at_begin(input("enter in somethin: "))
linklist.printlist()
```

When i tried to use the printlist method it infinite looped.I have realised that the problem is with the "curr=curr.link" statement , it seems to me that it does nothing

Comment: `node.link = link` looks wrong on principle. That almost certainly should be `self.link = link` instead (and same for all those other accesses that write to class attributes instead of instance attributes)